# Birthday next 7 days from 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to query my database regarding birthdays in next 7 days - 
with birthday date in two columns

```
  Name  Day   Month   
  Peter 15    8       
  Susi  20    8      
  Thor  14    9
```

Query = who has birthday next 7 days
Return

```
Peter 15 - 8   
Susi  20 - 8
```

any help welcome -
Regards
Thorsten

Comment: It might help to use a database's built-in date types. Anyways, what have you tried?

Comment: Separating the day and month requires a lot of logic... checking how many days in the month etc.  Use the Datestamp datatype, as @arxanas suggests.

Comment: hi - no homework - (I installed a new Database for my church and need to write a custom query for it ) - I know some basics - but not enough to get everything done.  Many answers I have found already in this forum - thanks to all who participate.  But cannot change the date in the tables - these are part of the system.  No Idea what a RDBMS is (big time Noob here)

Answer (score 4):

You did not specify RDBMS but this should return the results you want in **SQL Server**. These will check if the month in the table is less than the current month, if so then it will use the following year:

```
select *
from 
(
    select name,
        cast(case 
                when datepart(month, getdate()) > [month] 
                 and datepart(day, getdate()) > [day]
                then cast(datepart(year, dateadd(year, 1, getdate())) as varchar(4))
                else cast(datepart(year, getdate()) as varchar(4)) end + '-'
            + cast([month] as varchar(2)) + '-'
            + cast([day] as varchar(2)) as datetime) bd
    from t1
) x
where datediff(day, getdate(), bd) >= 0 
  and datediff(day, getdate(), bd) < 7
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f10c1/3)

Or:

```
select *
from 
(
    select name,
        cast(case 
        when datepart(month, getdate()) > [month] 
            and datepart(day, getdate()) > [day]
        then cast(datepart(year, dateadd(year, 1, getdate())) as varchar(4))
        else cast(datepart(year, getdate()) as varchar(4)) end + '-'
    + cast([month] as varchar(2)) + '-'
    + cast([day] as varchar(2)) as datetime) bd
    from t1
) x
where bd >= DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
    and bd < DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, getdate()), 7)
```

**MySQL version:**

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  select name,
    str_to_date(concat(case 
      when month(current_date()) > month
           and day(current_date()) > day
      then year(date_add(current_date, interval 1 year))
      else year(current_date()) 
    end, '-', month, '-', day), '%Y-%m-%d') birthdate
  from t1
) x
where birthdate >= Date(current_date())
  and birthdate < Date(Date_Add(current_date(), interval 7 day))
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5773f/5)

Comment: The year boundary causes problems, for example a birthday on January 1st and it's currently December 27th

Comment: Will that work at the end of the year? If it's 30 December 2012 then will the inner select cast the date for a birthday on 2 Jan as 2 Jan 2012 instead of 2013?

Comment: @bort - How about a CASE statement where if the month/day of getdate is > than the cast month/day of the bday, it gets the next year. Less than and it gets the current year. That be the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the second select statement from @bluefeet answer you can do something like this:

```
select * 
from  
( 
    select name,
        case when(
         cast(cast(datepart(year, getdate()) as varchar(4)) + '-' 
        + cast([bmonth] as varchar(2)) + '-' 
        + cast([bday] as varchar(2)) as datetime) > getdate())
        THEN
            cast(cast(datepart(year, getdate()) as varchar(4)) + '-' 
            + cast([bmonth] as varchar(2)) + '-' 
            + cast([bday] as varchar(2)) as datetime)

        ELSE

            cast(cast(datepart(year, getdate())+1 as varchar(4)) + '-' 
            + cast([bmonth] as varchar(2)) + '-' 
            + cast([bday] as varchar(2)) as datetime)
        END
        as bd 
    from @Names 
) x 
where bd >= DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
    and bd < DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, GETDATE()), 7)
```